# SQL Server XML exist()

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have some problems using the `exist()` and `value()` methods in SQL Server 2008.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <branches>
        <branch>
            <codelib>1</codelib>
            <name>Campus</name>
        </branch>
        <branch>
            <codelib>2</codelib>
            <name>47th</name>
        </branch>
        <branch>
            <codelib>3</codelib>
            <name>Mall</name>
        </branch>              
    </branches>
    <books>
        <book type="SF">
            <codb>11</codb>
            <title>Robots</title>
            <authors>
                <author>author1 robots</author>
                <author>author2 robots</author>
            </authors>
            <price>10</price>
            <stocks>
                <branch codelib="1" amount="10"/>
                <branch codelib="2" amount="5"/>
                <branch codelib="4" amount="15"/>
            </stocks>
            <from>20</from>
            <to>30</to>
        </book>
        <book type="poetry">
            <codb>12</codb>
            <title>Poetry book</title>
            <authors>
                <author>AuthorPoetry</author>
            </authors>
            <price>14</price>
            <stocks>
                <branch codelib="1" amount="7"/>
                <branch codelib="2" amount="5"/>
            </stocks>
            <from>25</from>
            <to>40</to>
        </book>       
        <book type="children">
            <codb>19</codb>
            <title>Faitytales</title>
            <authors>               
                <author>AuthorChildren</author>             
            </authors>
            <price>20</price>
            <stocks>
                <branch codelib="1" amount="10"/>
                <branch codelib="3" amount="55"/>
                <branch codelib="4" amount="15"/>
            </stocks>
            <from>70</from>
            <to>75</to>
        </book>       
        <book type="literature">
            <codb>19</codb>
            <title>T</title>
            <authors>
                <author>A</author>                
            </authors>
            <price>17</price>
            <stocks>
                <branch codelib="1" amount="40"/>
            </stocks>
            <from>85</from>
            <to>110</to>
        </book>
    </books>
</library>
```

Given this XML, I have to write a `SELECT` clause that will use `query()`, `value()` and `exist()` 2 times each, minimum. I can't even use `query()` and `exist()` in the same `SELECT`, as it appears that the `WHERE` clause has no effect whatsoever.

For example, I want to retrieve all the `<branch>` elements that are children of the book with the type `SF`, but the select statement

```
  declare @genre varchar(15)
  set @genre = 'SF'
  SELECT XMLData.query('//branch') from TableA
  WHERE XMLData.exist('//book[./@type = sql:variable("@genre")]') = 1
```

retrieves all the `<branch>` elements, not just the ones from the targeted book. I can't figure out what's wrong with my select. Also, I would appreciate a small example with `query()`, `exist()` and `value()` in the same select (is it possible to have nested select statements in sql xml?)

Answer (score 8):

Well, your XPath expression here is the "culprit":

```
query('//branch')
```

This says: select **all** `<branch>` nodes from the entire document. It is just doing what you're telling it to do, really....

What's wrong with this query here??

```
SELECT 
    XMLData.query('/library/books/book[@type=sql:variable("@genre")]//branch')
FROM dbo.TableA
```

That would retrieve all the `<branch>` subnodes for the `<book>` node that has `type="SF"` as an attribute....

What are you trying to achieve with your `query()`, `exist()` and `value()` all in the same statement?? Quite possibly, it can be done a lot easier....

Also: I think you're misinterpreting what `.exist()` in SQL Server XQuery does. If you have your statement here:

```
 SELECT (some columns)
 FROM dbo.TableA
 WHERE XMLData.exist('//book[@type = sql:variable("@genre")]') = 1
```

you're basically telling SQL Server to retrieve all rows from `dbo.TableA` where the XML stored in `XMLData` contains a `<book type=.....>` node - you are selecting rows from the table - **NOT** applying a selection to the `XMLData` column's content...

Comment: It's not that I want, but I have to use both query(), value() and exist() in the same statement. That's why I want to make some sort of filtering like in T-SQL, SELECT...WHERE...may something like nested SELECT statementsm if that's possible. I just want an example on how to achieve smth like that

Answer (score 4):

The XML you supplied does not lend itself to an `exist` statement. If you had multiple XML statements and needed to find the one where it contained some value, then the statement would have been more relevant.

The `where` clause you supplied just checks if the condition exists and if it does, selects all the `branches` elements, not just the one where the condition is true.
For example, the following (obviously) does not return anything:

```
SELECT @xmldata.query('//branch') from TableA
 WHERE @xmldata.exist('//book[./@type = "BLAH"]') = 1
```

But here is something to show you can use all three in one select statement.

```
SELECT T.c.query('./title').value('.', 'varchar(250)') as title, 
       T.c.exist('.[@type eq "SF"]') as IsSF
  from @xmldata.nodes('//book') T(c)
```

Comment: The SELECT you provided is close to what I need, tnx. One last problem...is it possible to have something like SELECT...WHERE x = (SELECT..WHERE), so that I can use value(), exist() and query() 2 times? Basically, a select (with all 3 functions) that will filter some values, and then another that uses the filtered nodes?

Answer (score 2):

It's more efficient with XML to filter using the cross apply operator to filter to the required node then select the query from the returned nodes. To query the child nodes you also need to include the root . in the query so in this case .//branch rather than //branch.

```
declare @genre varchar(15) = 'SF'
select l.query('.//branch') from TableA
cross apply XmlData.nodes('library/books/book[@type=sql:variable("@genre")]') n (l)
```

You can still add the exists clause if you want but this will actually add additional unnecessary overhead

```
WHERE XMLData.exist('//book[./@type = sql:variable("@genre")]') = 1
```

Hope this helps.
D